# xcode share data between iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, synchronization

I am building an app that will run on a user's iPhone and iPad. People will enter information on either device. I am looking for methods in which the data can be synchronized between the devices.

Would I have to force people into something like iCloud or Dropbox?

Comment: If you can wait till iOS 5, [iCloud](http://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php) might be something to look at. Alternatively, you can develop your own backend system.

Comment: I've thought about the former but don't think I can force people to any cost-based solution. The latter would be cost-based for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think It would be a good idea to consider using iCloud as iOS 5 will soon make this the accepted standard and people will expect it.

Comment: well I don't suppose we're yet able to fully discuss iCloud here, but will it be able to syncronize non Apple data - i.e., not contacts, bookmarks, etc?

Comment: Yes I believe so if you have access to the iOS 5 developer docs and search iCloud it tells about it in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want any sort of server-side solution (i.e. iCloud or something you write yourself) then have you thought of bluetooth / wifi - assuming the users will have their devices near to each other then you could sync directly from device to device.

However, I would probably have some sort of server that did the sync and stored the data - you could make this free for a certain amount of data and then charge for anything more than that - hopefully that would recoup the cost of running the server.

Comment: Does anyone know how the Things.app manages their syncing between computers and devices?